# Retroarch js emulator not working on webpage

Tags: emulation, emscripten

I am trying to develop a simple web page that allows a user to play a retro game (like Mario) using his browser. For this I have decided to use the js emulators that have been compiled from retroarch using emscripten. I have been told that some of the js emulators available on libretro website currently (https://buildbot.libretro.com/stable/1.7.0/emscripten/) do not work properly (example: n64 js emulator). So, I am trying to use the older version available on play-roms.com but I have not been able to make it work even after a lot of work.

**The problem**
I am trying to just replicate this game page to work locally on my machine: https://play-roms.com/nintendo-64/super-mario-64 Since, it is mostly dependent on HTML, CSS and JS, I simply copied all the HTML,CSS, JS files and also the emulator and .mem files. When I tried to make them work locally, they simply do not work. I get a constant warning in console in infinite loop:

> "RetroArch [libretro INFO] :: mupen64plus: Memory initialized"

This warning does not allow the game to load. Please note that I do not get any other warning or errors on the console which are not already happening on the original mario page of play-roms from which I copied the files.

I assume that the problem is happening because of some issue with .mem file. Next, I tried to fetch the mem file from play-roms server itself (just for testing purpose) but that also did not help. (Please note that I am aware of CORS and know how to handle it). I still get the same error even when mem file is fetched from play-roms

I talked to someone who has worked in this area before and he confirmed that he too faced the exact same issue of "Memory initialized" in infinite loop when he tried it. He too could not solve it.

Please note that copying some other website is not my goal. I am just trying to make the retroarch js emulators work for my website.

Comment: hi, did you found any solution on this?

Comment: If you look at the embedded working sample on the retroarch site, and compare it to the source or binaries that are available, you'll see the public source is incomplete.